# MAUI .NET 8 MainSplashScreen Duration?

Tags: c#, maui

I want to apply a 10-second intro when entering a mobile application and I use only one image file for this.

But I couldn't do this for 10 seconds. I'm trying the application on a real Android device. The intro goes to the home screen without even taking 1 second, but I want it to go to the home page after that picture appears on the screen for 10 seconds.

Please I would be happy if you help.

```
<!-- Splash Screen -->
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splash.png">
    <Duration>10000</Duration>
</MauiSplashScreen>
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: What you tried isn't supported, you can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen) for what's possible with the cross-platform approach. Why ten seconds? That's an awfully long time and smells like bad user experience to me. What's the purpose of that? As a user, I'd expect an app to load as fast as possible.

Comment: the purpose of the splash screen is to show the user something while your app initializes.  You should make it as short as possible, not longer.  This is a bad UX design

Comment: Something you can do is add a loading screen to your app, which can be used to show animations and such while you're still loading data in the background. This is not to be confused with the splash scren, which only is shown while the app initializes. Ideally, you would also cache certain data in order to show your app's content as quickly as possible the next time it starts.

Answer (score 3):

You can not reduce duration of the Splash Screen in the Android.

This is the google design. From the android 12, the android will use the [SplashScreen Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen) to show the splash screen. It only customizes these parts: icon, window background, exit animation.